# Websocket connection failed: connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to implement a guacamole (remote connection to pc through browser) but when trying to connect through internet, I get the following errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429
>   (Too Many Requests)

&

> app.js?v=0.9.13-incubating:129 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://remote.company.com/guacamole/websocket-tunnel?token=E8577744842BFA261785C52CAA309CBC6FC5DBE262E7508FF6F49C1821AB6F58&GUAC_DATA_SOURCE=mysql&GUAC_ID=1&GUAC_TYPE=c&GUAC_WIDTH=917&GUAC_HEIGHT=922&GUAC_DPI=110&GUAC_AUDIO=audio%2FL8&GUAC_AUDIO=audio%2FL16&GUAC_IMAGE=image%2Fjpeg&GUAC_IMAGE=image%2Fpng&GUAC_IMAGE=image%2Fwebp'
>   failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Thus a websocket connection could not be established and everything goes through HTTP which means slow performance.

In my opinion, this is caused by an extra proxy I've set up in order to reach the site from outside.

Here is the setup:

url: https://remote.company.com

Port 443 is forwarded to firewall: Proxy from remote.company.com to `<IP ADDRESS guacamole server:8080>` 
In the Apache vhost, I have the following proxy's in order to establish websocket tunnel:

```
<Location /guacamole/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/guacamole/
</Location>

<Location /guacamole/websocket-tunnel>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
    ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
</Location>
```

All according to the [documentation](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/proxying-guacamole.html)
What do I need to change in order to establish websocket tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

as I see in your configuration everything seems to be ok. please check if your configuration has this:

- Apache >= 2.4.5
- enabled `mod_proxy_wstunnel`.

This is how appears in my PC `LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so`

Comment: The mod is already enabled and Apache version is OK. The problem turned out to be the proxy server. It's a Junos ssl box, which don't support the ws:\ protocol. So I've used another port (8443) and forwarded this to the server in question. Now the websocket tunnel is working like a charm. Thanks anyway